# Proxy Authentication Failed error

Tags: java, authentication, ftp

I'm trying to access an FTP server through an FTP SITE Proxy to bypass a firewall using `it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient` I know my username/password is correct because I can connect using FileZilla. I tried using `Authenticator`, but it has no use. Code:

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.connectors.FTPProxyConnector;
...
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FTPProxyConnector connector = new FTPProxyConnector(String "proxyHost", int proxyPort);
        client.setConnector(connector);

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
             public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                       return new PasswordAuthentication("proxyUser", "proxyPass".toCharArray());
         }});

        System.setProperty("ftp.proxyHost", "proxyHost");
        System.setProperty("ftp.proxyPort", "proxyPort");
        System.setProperty("ftp.proxyUser", "proxyUser");
        System.setProperty("ftp.proxyPass", "proxyPass");

        System.out.println("Proxy Accessed");

        client.connect("ftpHost");
        client.login("ftpUser", "ftpPass");
```

Gives me this error: `java.io.IOException: Proxy authentication failed`

Things I have tried:

- Using the alternate constructor `(String, int, String, String)`.
- Removing `Authenticator`
- Using just `Authenticator`, without the FTPProxyConnector
- Authenticating before setting the connector, and vice versa.

However, when I am JUST using the Authenticator, I get a different error saying `Connection timed out`.

Both errors occur on line `client.connect("ftpHost");`

**ANY** help would be appreciated.

Note: [The FTP Proxy Connector](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/api/it/sauronsoftware/ftp4j/connectors/FTPProxyConnector.html)

EDIT: I found out that the proxy is used to bypass a Firewall-1 Checkpoint -- if this helps.

Comment: Where you had attached the `Authenticator` and `FTPProxyConnector`?

Comment: Also why don't you use the other constructor of `FTPProxyConnector` [FTPProxyConnector(java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/api/it/sauronsoftware/ftp4j/connectors/FTPProxyConnector.html#FTPProxyConnector(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli I tried that constructor calling for (host, port, username, password) and it still gives me the same error, saying the proxy authentication has failed. I also imported Authenticator and FTPProxyConnector at the top.

Comment: Please improve your first question instead of posting it again.

Comment: How would you like me to improve it? Please tell me what I need to add because I believe I have posted everything that is relevant to my problem here.

Comment: I actually implemented his suggestions and I still received an error. I also answered to both of his comments; unless there are other comments that are invisible to me(?), I believe I considered the only solution that was given to me.

Comment: I will add more detail is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution...

I discovered that the FTP client was responding with a different response code:

`200-User <username> authenticated by FireWall-1 authentication`

In the source code of `FTPProxyConnector`, a response code of anything other than the regular

`230-Connected to server. Logging in...`

will throw an error.

I had to decompile the class file for `FTPProxyConnector` and then modify the source code, then recompile and save it back to the jar. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Check password property name. It's name is ftp.proxyPassword, and not ftp.proxyPass.

```
System.setProperty("ftp.proxyUser", "proxyUser");
System.setProperty("ftp.proxyPassword", "proxyPass");
```

Try it and let us know your results!

Comment: Thanks for the fix, but I'm still getting a `java.io.IOException: Proxy authentication failed` error. I tried using your method with and without the `FTPProxyConnector`, but it was no use. When I don't use the `FTPProxyConnector`, though, I get an error `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`.

Answer (score 1):

Check password property name. It's name is ftp.proxyPassword, and not ftp.proxyPass.

```
System.setProperty("ftp.proxyUser", "proxyUser");
System.setProperty("ftp.proxyPassword", "proxyPass");
```

Try it and let us know your results!

Comment: Thanks for the fix, but I'm still getting a `java.io.IOException: Proxy authentication failed` error. I tried using your method with and without the `FTPProxyConnector`, but it was no use. When I don't use the `FTPProxyConnector`, though, I get an error `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`.